# Show message on wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I have created a form. On success of the form, I am redirecting the user the their dashboard. Now, I want to be able to show a success message/notice on the dashboard.

What is the convention to show such messages ?

Comment: Have you tried [our search engine](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=admin+message)?

Comment: Are you using Settings API?

Comment: @toscho I did but had misunderstood the function. Thanks.

Comment: @Mamaduka if you mean the options page, I have. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you redirect the user to the admin dashboard pass on a GET variable named "success_notice", for example. So you get a URL like this: `/wp-admin/index.php?success_notice=1`.

With that setup, just add the code that shows the success message on the dashboard only if that GET variable is set.

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'wpse75629_admin_notice');

function wpse75629_admin_notice()
{
    global $pagenow;

    // Only show this message on the admin dashboard and if asked for
    if ('index.php' === $pagenow && ! empty($_GET['success_notice']))
    {
        echo '<div class="updated"><p>Your success message!</p></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, had misunderstood the function of the "admin_notices" hook.